# Can I output a node CCK value in a Views header in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, views, theming, entities, panels

- I am using Panels to display a View on each node of a content type.
- I am using an override of  views-view.tpl.php to theme the output of the view.
- I need to display a CCK value from each node that the View appears on in the header area of the View.
- The CCK field I need to output is not a field called by the view so I can't use a token replacement in the "Header" area of the View GUI.
- I can't code the header into the content type node template because then it will show up even if the View has no results.

I have tried:

```
print $my_cck_field[0]['display_url'];
```

and

```
echo field_view_field('node', $node, '$my_cck_field');
```

in views-view.tpl.php and I get no output.

Is it possible to access the CCK data for the node a View appears on from inside views-view.tpl.php ?

Comment: Just a small note, in Drupal 7 there is no CCK any more, simply fields. What used do be CCK is in core now.